# Customize SQL Server Report Builder Wizard

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I'm a new NAV dev and currently learning how to generate reports. Everything works, but I always end up having to do the exact same steps over and over. What I am wanting to do, is create a custom template for the wizard that already has some things preconfigured, like the interactive sorting, the header being the caption params, etc.

Is something like this possible or will I have to do it one by one from now until the end of time?

Comment: How far I know, you can't do that like you described. What I do, is like @Kush described in his answer. I have multiple companies that I'm developing report to. For each one, i made myself a template that contains some basic layout and information for that company (Company Logo, name, address, phone etc.). Then if i need to make some new reports, this will save me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Not Really. What you can do is create your report object templates, and export them as .fob/.txt, and then All you have to do is import them in when you need to.

What I also do is to copy existing report objects that are similar to the report I have to design, and work from that.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The report is based on some record. When switching the record, it breaks everything anyway, so you end up having to redo everything.

Comment: What if you create an application that outputs .txt version of the objects? For example, It your app reads what fields/tables NAV has, and from your application, you can use a simple form to generate that .txt file?

Comment: I understand your idea, but that is a lot of effort and has far too many scenarios. I was looking for a simple and flexible solution, but it seems, there is none. Too many fools designing away.

Comment: yeap, when I started with NAV, I was thinking along the same lines. But now I just go ahead and use the object designer.